# Integrate $\int \frac{x^3 e^x \:dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Tags: exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $$\int \frac{x^3 e^x \:dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

My try:

I used Parts by writing integral as:

$$I=\int x^2 e^x {\frac{x\:dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}$$ we get

$$I=x^2 e^x\sqrt{x^2-1}-\int (x^2-2x+2)e^x \sqrt{x^2-1}dx$$

But the other integral has become more complicated

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification which I hope will be helpful.

$$ \int (x^2 -2x+2)e^x \sqrt{ x^2-1}$$
$$\cot(cosec^{-1} x)=\sqrt{ x^2-1}$$

Let $cosec^{-1} x=u$ then:

$ cosec (u)=\frac{1}{\sin u} =x$

$dx=\frac{-\cos u}{\sin^2 u}du$

substituting we get:

$$ \int (x^2 -2x+2)e^x \sqrt{ x^2-1}=\int(\frac{1}{\sin^2 u}-\frac{2}{\sin u} +2)cotan (u) .\frac{-\cos u}{\sin^2 u} e^{1/\sin u}du$$

$\frac{-\cos u}{\sin^2 u} e^{1/\sin u}=(e^{1/\sin x})'$

$\frac{-\cos u}{\sin^2 u} e^{1/\sin u}du= dv$

$v=\frac{1}{\sin u}$

$(\frac{1}{\sin^2 u}-\frac{2}{\sin u} +2)cotan (u)=t$

I think you could now do it .